# Geany / GCC setup for c and GTK

Tags: setup

I'm having problems finding information on the codes for compile and build using Geany / GCC.

My compile command is:    gcc -Wall -c "%f" `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
      Compile is OK, although I really don't know what "%f" means

My build command is:      gcc -Wall -o "f" "%e" `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
      Build fails with error:
            Process failed (Failed to change to directory '*' (No such file or directory)
      This begs the question of what "%e" is.
      Where is the directory called out in these lines?
      If the compile is ok, it found the correct directory.  What is causing the build to fail for changing directory?

BTW:  The file I'm trying to run is just a console app....Hello World

```
  'GCC -g HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld '    in terminal works fine
   I just can't seem to figure how to use the Compile and Build 
           under 'Set Build Commands'
```

One other.....I type    MAN GCC       Response is: 'No manual entry for gcc'

Sorry for long question(s).  I don't know how to search for answers of the "%e" and "%f" questions.  The Geany manual doesn't show it.  I can't find a manual for GCC

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to run the same app as you for the same reasons (trying to learn C/C++ and GTK+) but not having a lot of success.

I don't have a complete answer for you, but perhaps just a push in the right direction.
You can read about the various "%" flags here:
https://wiki.geany.org/howtos/configurebuildmenu

it states:
Within the command and working directory entries the following character strings are substituted when the command is run.

%f - replaced by the filename of the file selected in the editor when the menu item is selected.

%e - replaced by the same filename but without the last extension.

%d - replaced by the absolute path of the directory of the file selected in the editor when the menu item is selected.

%p - replaced by the absolute path of the base directory of the currently open project.

More than one substitution can be made so for instance %d\%e.exe would be used for the absolute filename of an executable on a windows system.

Regards,
Jeff (the BigGreenOne)

Answer (score 0):

this link helped me - I'm looking now for the include files place

https://content.instructables.com/ORIG/F5K/ISBF/KFGTTI27/F5KISBFKFGTTI27.pdf